# How to replicate multiple databases into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-administration

I have multiple databases on sql server 2016 (lets say 50) with identical tables but different data in each table. How can I replicate this data into one single database with all of the data in the corresponding tables so that I can view it all from one place?

Ideally I'd also have a column showing where the data came from.

I have tried different variations of replication, but none of them work for me

Snapshot overwrites the differences. Merge was having issues in general with multiple db's to one. transaction is working but identical ID's give it issues.
 maybe I am setting one of the options wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Write your own stored procedure that first UNIONs all the tables and then does a MERGE (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) with the target table. The proc can be called from a SQL job that runs at specific interval. In the target table, you will need to have a column with the source database name so that the ID and database name can be used as join criteria for the MERGE statement.

```
SELECT 'SourceDatabase1' as SourceDatabase, Col1, Col2 FROM 
SourceDatabase1.schema.Table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SourceDatabase2', Col1, Col2 FROM 
SourceDatabase2.schema.Table
```

### UNION ALL

Or create an AFTER TRIGGER in each source database table that MERGEs to the target table. You will still need the source database name in the target table as a JOIN criteria.

Answer (score 1):

[SymmetricDS](https://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) can be used for this use case.   You can use a transform that will add the database/node id to each table while sending it up to your shared central database.   This allows you to replicate to a central without changing your 50 existing databases.  Also if you need replication to be bi-directional there is support for a column match router in SymmetricDS.   This will be used to analyze the row for the database/node id column mentioned above to determine which of the 50 databases to send the replicated change.